# Can't get stored procedure result

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my stored  procedure with a cursor, I got the results but when I try to get that value into table I can't get it. Please help me.

Here is my C# code

```
string sql = "ForTaxReport";
tdsTPDPay.TaxReportRow dataRowLog = new tdsTPDPay.TaxReportDataTable().NewTaxReportRow();

if (base.Transaction != null)
{
    base.Command = new SqlCommand(sql, base.Connection, base.Transaction);
}
else
{
    base.Command = new SqlCommand(sql, base.Connection);
}

base.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
base.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayrollDate", GetNull(date));
base.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", GetNull(ID));

base.OpenConnection();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(base.Command);
tdsTPDPay.TaxReportDataTable dt = new tdsTPDPay.TaxReportDataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
return dt;
```

Comment: What error/exception are you getting ?

Comment: nothing.but i cant get result.

Comment: Then you'll need to show the stored proc code as well. 'Nothing' would mean that your select statement in the sproc found no matches.

Comment: stored procedure return rows.But when i fill that data into dt table it cant appear